# Logging in with FireBase facebook authentication, getCurrentUser() keeps returning null

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am struggling right now to pass on the CurrentUser when I am logging in with Facebook (with firebase authentication). It has been working before, but as I log into my application now, the currentuser keeps returning null.

I think it might be because I am already logged into the app with Facebook, but the firebase authentication sees me as a new user. However, I am not sure.

My onStart on the LogIn page looks the following:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null && AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: We run this 2" + currentUser + mAuth);
        ItemHolder.getInstance().setUser(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
        updateUI();
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: else run in onstart");
    }
}
```

The ItemHolder object is a singleton used to store the information of the User. However, it never reaches that, because the user is always null.

I have added an AuthStateListener, and it says that there is no currentuser. My problem is that I have no idea how to retrieve the currentUser when it keeps returning null? Everything else in my login activity follows the firebase quick guide provided, to login with Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed my problem.

So I tried to add the currentUser to actually be apart of my updateUi() method. Then it seemed my problem was, that I updated the UI in my facebookCallback(), which seemed to change the activity before actually handling the login.

So now my code looks the following:

```
private void facebookCallback() {
    FBLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: onSuccess");
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }
```

And

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: We run this");
                        updateUI(user);
                    }
                    else{
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```